# Visual Studio For Mac Debugging Unit Tests

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-mac

I just downloaded VS 2019 for Mac.  Console projects debugging works fine hitting break points. If I try to debug a MSTest or NUnit test project the break points are ignored with no error message.

I have tried changing the options, I am in debug mode, I have tried restarting, and creating new projects. I have downloaded the MSTest.TestFramework, and MSTest.TestAdapter from nuget. None of these have worked.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Is it a .NET Core project?

Comment: Yes, .NET 2.2  .

Comment: Did you have Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk in reference list? https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmplib/blob/11.1.0/Tests/CSharpCore/Tests.NetStandard.csproj#L38

Comment: @Mwspencer Hi, any update for this issue? Do you debug the test project by F5 or choose debug test in test explorer or something? For test project, we can't start debugging by F5.

Comment: @Lance Li-MSFT, Sorry been on a windows sys the past couple days.  Yes using Debug Test is the trick.  I never realized there was a difference Running and Debugging test because I just use keyboard shortcuts on windows VS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to "Menu" -> "View" - "Test'. 
Find your test... right click on it... and "Debug test"

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I never realized ctrl r + t on windows was Debug Test not  Run Test.  So now this all makes sense.  Thank you